# Problem working with Exif Data in Xamarin Forms and understanding Android path system

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, exif, android-storage

I have a problem handling exif data in Xamarin Forms, I explain:

1. My app takes picture with MediaPlugin and the image path is 
   `file.Path=`"**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.appname/files/Pictures/Sample/someName.jpg**"
2. Use **ExifInterface** for put on the image my exif data (on the same path)

   ````
   ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(file.Path);
   newExif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagUserComment, "Hello photo!");
   newExif.SaveAttributes();```
   ````

Now the problem begin, if i use `GetAttribute` on this path i can see my exif data but if i copy the image phisically from "***\Phone\Pictures\Sample***" on my PC and get into details no one of my exif data is displayed (only camera data like white balance etc).

Now i readed that the **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.....** is the "master" path of the resource and the other are "virtual link" but i don't now how to reach the other image path.

How can i handle this? How can i see the exif data in the images on my PC copy?

I hope my explanation is clear

Comment: are you SURE that you are copying the image from the same path that you added the EXIF data to?  I suspect that MediaPlugin is returning you a copy of the image that you are adding EXIF data to, but then you are copying the original copy of the photo from the image gallery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's probably that MediaPlugin is returning me a copy but at this point i can't figure it out how to put my exif on the original image because i don't know the path. I've tried use `string destFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures); ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(destFolder + "/Sample/test_12.jpg");` but it can't find the path and crash

Comment: I tried to use the adb root. I open the path, I just found the `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.appname/files/`, `/Pictures/Sample/someName.jpg` is virtual link, so I advice you can copy your Image(MediaPlugin is returning to you) to the public folder.But the existed data, it cannot be accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, i'm tring to copy the image but even here i've some path problems... here my code: `string destFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), picName);
                File.Copy(file.Path, destFolder, true);` cause the error: "**Could not find a part of the path** "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i've used this workaround:

I've create a new folder in the ExternalStorage Absolute Path (that is the folder that you can see in Windows File Explorer)

```
var directoryname = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "MY_APP");
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryname);
string jpgFilename = Path.Combine(directoryname, picName);
File.Copy(file.Path, jpgFilename, true);

ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(jpgFilename);
newExif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagUserComment, "Ketama126");
newExif.SaveAttributes();
```

This create a new folder called "MY_APP" and inside copy the image returned from CrossMedia, here you can save the exif data